# assertion GTK_IS_WIDGET failed

Tags: gtk, vala

Данная ошибка происходит при запуске моей программы

```
(exec:4287): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_show_all: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
```

Пишу на языке Vala. Вот код метода, после которого появились краши:

```
public static string select(){
    string output;
    var dialog = new Gtk.FileChooserDialog("Open File", ClassMain.mainWindow,
        Gtk.FileChooserAction.OPEN,
        Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL, Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL,
        Gtk.ResponseType.ACCEPT, Gtk.ResponseType.ACCEPT);
    if(dialog.run() == Gtk.ResponseType.ACCEPT) {
        output = (dialog.get_filename());
        dialog.destroy();
        return output;
    }
    return "";
}
```

При компиляции можно заметить набор ошибок (warning), которые, однако, не мешают компиляции (а зря):

```
/home/ancient/code/vala/VGIDE/file.vala.c: In function ‘class_file_select’:
/home/ancient/code/vala/VGIDE/file.vala.c:61:2: warning: passing argument 4 of ‘gtk_file_chooser_dialog_new’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  _tmp1_ = (GtkFileChooserDialog*) gtk_file_chooser_dialog_new ("Open File", _tmp0_, GTK_FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_OPEN, GTK_RESPONSE_CANCEL, GTK_RESPONSE_CANCEL, GTK_RESPONSE_ACCEPT, GTK_RESPONSE_ACCEPT, NULL);
  ^
In file included from /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h:99:0,
             from /home/ancient/code/vala/VGIDE/file.vala.c:9:
/usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtkfilechooserdialog.h:63:12: note: expected ‘const gchar *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
 GtkWidget *gtk_file_chooser_dialog_new              (const gchar          *title,
        ^
```

P. S. Прошу добавить тег "Vala", т. к. это основная тема данного топика.

UPD: После фикса: (ошибка при запуске та-же)

```
file.vala:7.4-7.12: warning: Gtk.Stock has been deprecated since 3.10
file.vala:8.4-8.12: warning: Gtk.Stock has been deprecated since 3.10
/home/ancient/code/vala/VGIDE/file.vala.c: In function ‘class_file_select’:
/home/ancient/code/vala/VGIDE/file.vala.c:61:2: warning: ‘GtkStock’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  _tmp1_ = (GtkFileChooserDialog*) gtk_file_chooser_dialog_new ("Open File", _tmp0_, GTK_FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_OPEN, GTK_STOCK_CANCEL, GTK_RESPONSE_CANCEL, GTK_STOCK_OPEN, GTK_RESPONSE_ACCEPT, NULL);
  ^
/home/ancient/code/vala/VGIDE/file.vala.c:61:2: warning: ‘GtkStock’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
Compilation succeeded - 2 warning(s)
```

О. Заменил все стоки на строки с соответствующими названиями и при компиляции ошибки пропали. Но краш, указанный в начале топика, ещё случается.

Answer (score 1):

Как можно заметить в сообщении об ошибке написано `expected ‘const gchar *’ but argument is of type ‘int’`. То есть, по-русски, нужна строка, а вы вместо четвертого и шестого аргумента передаёте число. Из [примера](https://developer.gnome.org/gnome-devel-demos/stable/filechooserdialog.vala.html.en) видно, что нужно передавать не `Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL` и `Gtk.ResponseType.ACCEPT`, а `Gtk.Stock.CANCEL` и `Gtk.Stock.OPEN`.

Обновление:
Убрал из инициализации статической переменной `new WindowMain();` в классе `ClassMain` и добавил этот код в `public static int main`: `mainWindow = new WindowMain();` и все заработало.

Comment: При запуске тот-же краш, но ошибка меняется: (в топике апдейт)

Comment: @Linuxoid Запустил ваш код, все работает, наверное, ошибка в другом. Сделайте минимальный рабочий пример.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6Fw2UI0CiGKVmVGX1FJUUFya0k/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Linuxoid обновил ответ.

Comment: Не работает - диалог выбора файла не видит окно.

Comment: @Linuxoid что значит «не видит»? Напишите подробнее.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31138/discussion-between-linuxoid-and-im-ieee).